# Jsr 352 - forcing to step regardless the status

Tags: jsr352, jberet, jbatch

I'm using jberet implementation of jsr 352.

My purpose is to provide a final step in which I send an email with batch information status.

Therefore, even if the previous step (can be either batchlet or a chunk) terminate with unexpected error, I must go through the final step and report what happened.

What is the best approach to do this? Maybe using some listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `javax.batch.api.listener.JobListener#afterJob` is the best place to do that. See its [javadoc here](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/batch/api/listener/JobListener.html).

Comment: So instead of creating a step I send mail directly from listener, is it correct?